# Comparing a dictionary value with a list and returning keys in list's order in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {'meeting': 311, 'dinner': 451, 'tonight': 572, 'telling': 992, 'one.': 1000}
```

and a list like this:

```
top_indices = [311, 992, 451]
```

I want to compare the dictionary with the list and return the keys of the dictionary. I'm able to do that using this code:

```
[keys for keys, indices in dictionary.items() if indices in top_indices]
```

This is giving me the result

```
['meeting',  'dinner', 'telling']
```

But I want the original order of the list to be unchanged, like this:

```
['meeting', 'telling',  'dinner']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does indices unique for all items, if so you can try to reverse dict and find values by keys using for loop and append to a list.

Comment: Its not good to name variables like `dictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invert the dictionary:

```
inverse = {index: key for key, index in dictionary.items()}
```

Now you can look up the keys in the correct order:

```
[inverse[index] for index in top_indices]
```

Another way would be

```
list(map(inverse.__getitem__, top_indices))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you swap the keys and the values it would be very easy.
Try this:

```
dictionary = {311:'meeting', 451: 'dinner', 572:'tonight', 992:'telling', 1000:'one.'}
top_indices = [311, 992, 451]
x = []
for i in top_indices:
    x.append(dictionary.get(i))
```